# Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Cannot convert URL 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0' to a file

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

I'm building the Google Maps demo from Android Coding on youtube. I built the app, but for some reason I keep getting the error message

> Cannot convert URL 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0' to a file.

Here is my `build.gradle`(Project Google Maps Demo):

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

    buildscript {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
            mavenLocal()

        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'


            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
            maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
            maven {
                url "https://maven.google.com"
            }
        }
    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

Can anyone help?
EDIT: Copied and pasted the same code twice, here is my actual build.gradle(module: app)**

Here is my `app/build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.zydavia.googlemapsdemo"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation files('com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0')
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.1.0'
}
```

Comment: Post the module/build.gradle file

Comment: posted! Can you see the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line:

```
//implementation files('com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0')
```

Comment: still no binkie. I'm also warned before I run the program that my "Configuration is still incorrect" and ask if I want to continue anyways. I do. I've tried updating Build.gradle, and google play and still doesn't work.

Comment: @fiendishbrokeboi Do you have the same error or another one? It is not clear

Comment: Thank you! I did have the same error but after restarting Android Studio, it works!

Comment: Hi @fiendishbrokeboi if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.